# Invariant Violation: `requireNativeComponent`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've created my project using `create-react-native-app AppName` and then I've installed *expo* to run it on my device, because without it is too slow, and the I tried to install *LinearGradient* (but the same error occurred also using other packages) and this is the error message:

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BVLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager.

I tried to install *pods*, then I use `expo AppRegistry` but nothing it doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?
And why when I try to run *react-native* without using expo on --device it takes 10 minutes.
Feel free to link me to others links, I've already read this article (https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) but it doesn't work and every time I had to start the app manually from xcode.
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#troubleshooting)?

Comment: It doesn't work again, I didn't understand the step 3, when it says: ios/**.xcworkspace file instead of ios./**.xcodeproj

Comment: Well I guess the problem is that you're using expo. Since LinearGradient is adding native code you'd need to eject.